# Add Comma Before & in reference list

Tags: bibtex, punctuation, apa-style

I am relatively new to LaTex and I am using TexMaker on Linux for my thesis. I am using the following code for my document and in particular for my reference list:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,parskip=half+]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}



\begin{document}

\bibliography{Literaturverzeichnis1} 
\nocite{Miller2012}

\end{document}
```

The citing is fine, there is just the problem, that I need a comma after the last name before the &-sign. I looked for solutions but i can't find any for apacite in bibtex.

```
@Article{Miller2012,
Title                    = {Theories of Willpower Affect Sustained Learning},
Author                   = {Miller, E. M. and Walton, G. M. and Dweck, C.S. and Job, V. and Trzesniewski, K. H., and McClure, S. M.},
Journal                  = {PLoS ONE},
Year                     = {2012},
Pages                    = {e38680},
Volume                   = {7}
```

I tried it with \renewcommand but it didn't work.

[image]

Missing following comma: Trzesniewski, K.H.**,** & McClure blabla

Can anyone help? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Remove the comma after `K. H.` in the author field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apacite` style provides `\BLCL` for this.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Miller2012,
Title   = {Theories of Willpower Affect Sustained Learning},
Author  = {Miller, E. M. and Walton, G. M. and Dweck, C.S. and Job, V. 
           and Trzesniewski, K. H. and McClure, S. M.},
Journal = {PLoS ONE},
Year    = {2012},
Pages   = {e38680},
Volume  = {7},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}}

\begin{document}

\cite{Miller2012}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I removed all unnecessary packages and used `filecontents*` in order to make the example self-contained. Just use your bib file yourself.

[image]

Note: there was a stray comma in your code, after `Trzesniewski, K. H.`, which I removed too.

For the comma also between two authors, the command to modify is `\BCBT`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}%
  \renewcommand{\BCBT}{,}%
}
```

Comment: Great, thx! How can I expand this, so that it also puts the comma after only two authors (e.g. Buss, A.H., & Perry, M.)? For now it puts it only after three or more authors. The APA-Manual requires a comma before the &-sign after two or more authors (no comma with one author).

Comment: @tianalana I added the code